# How to select a sprite with the mouse in c# XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, sprites, monogame, picking

I'm attempting to create a chess game, for the movement I need to be able to click on a piece with the mouse, and then the square I'd like to move it to. Each piece on the board is a sprite, and I'm struggling to find a way to select a sprite in order to then move it, what would be the best way to do this? I'm programming in c# with XNA framework btw. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This problem is called "picking" - [searching "XNA picking" turns up some promising looking tutorials and past Q&A that might help you](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xna+picking&ia=web).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to make a rectangle for the position and hitbox of each of your chess pieces.
After that make a rectangle for the mouse pointer, and use the Rectangle.Intersects method to check if your mouse hitbox intersects with one of the pieces hitboxes, and of course do your logic there.